# How to disable the options in select element based on another select element with same option values?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have to disable the slect options based on value selected in another select.

```
<select   ng-model="myval" ng-options="lst as lst.txt  for lst in valuedata track by $index" ></select>


   <select   ng-model="myval" ng-options="lst as lst.txt  for lst in valuedata track by $index" ></select>
```

here I get same data,but my requirement is,if I select two in first dropdown I need to disable the values less than two in second dropdown and If i select two in dropdown two I need to disable the values greater than two in first dropdown.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: you can refer this:https://stackoverflow.com/a/38417100/7951293

Comment: @ Nithin Charly No I need to disable

Comment: @pbsbr: see the answer for disabling.

Answer (score 0):

Try following code:

```
<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp1', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
    //get your value and compare
});
var app2 = angular.module('myApp2', []);
app2.controller('myCtrl2', function($scope) {
    //get your value and compare
});

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by **`disable when`** syntax of **angular 1.4+** version. [Read Doc.](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions)

In your problem, I suggest to have 2 different `ng-model` properties(*though you can achieve this by single prop as well*).,  you can do like:

```
    <select ng-model="data.first" ng-options="lst.txt as lst.txt disable when lst.txt > data.second for lst in valuedata">
    </select>

    <select ng-model="data.second" ng-options="lst.txt as lst.txt disable when lst.txt < data.first for lst in valuedata">
   </select>
```

Here is [working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/L2wvfftr/).